Как сделать Телеграм бот обязательной подписки для выдачи файлов в канале APK
Здравствуйте подскажите как можно сделать бота в телеграм который выдает файлы
К примеру я выложил пост в телеграм канале про программу и внизу сделал кнопку скачать и когда человек нажимает на данную кнопку скачать его перекидывает в телеграм бота первое сообщение бота что бы скачать файл необходимо подписать на каналы
Человек подписался и бот выдает файл к этому посту
И так к каждому посту когда человек нажимает кнопку скачать бот выдает файл к этому посту

А вы, собственно, какой ответ ожидаете?
